# Delete Previous Line And Replace It With New Line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, sleep

My current code is the following:

```
for a in xrange (60, 0, -1):  
    b = "Sleeping for " + str(a) + " seconds\r"
    print b,
    sleep(1)
```

The only issue I have with it is that when it goes from 2 digit numbers to 1 digit numbers it prints secondss instead of seconds. How can I modify my code to properly replace the line when a goes from 2 digits to 1. Also, after the script is done printing the "Sleeping for __ seconds" lines am I able to replace that with a line that says "Sleeping for 60 seconds complete"

Comment: You may call number string with `zfill` as `'1'.zfill(2)` which returns `01` whereas `'12'.zfill(2)` returns `12`

Comment: Try using `b = "Sleeping for {:2} seconds\r".format(a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using string formatting?

```
for a in xrange (60, 0, -1):  
    print "Sleeping for %2d seconds...\r" % a, 
    sleep(1)
print "Sleeping for 60 seconds complete!"
```

Comment: Works perfectly when you replace sleep(a) with sleep(1)

Comment: @DanteArcese I thought you wanted it to sleep a different period each time. fixed

Comment: Now that it is fixed yes

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the comma in the print line to see the print output

Answer (score 0):

you can print out an equal-length string of spaces to cover it up:

```
for a in xrange(60, 0, -1):
    out = "sleeping for {} seconds\r".format(a)
    sys.stdout.write(out)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    clear = " " * len(out)
    sys.stdout.write(clear + "\r")
print "Done"
```

you can also add ellipses to `out` to cover it up:

```
for a in xrange(60, 0, -1):
    out = "sleeping for {} seconds..\r".format(a)
    sys.stdout.write(out)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
print "Done"
```